# Wix bootstrapper trouble detecting .net framework

Tags: .net, wix

I am trying to detect whether or not the .Net framework is installed on the client's computer before I install my application. If it isn't I include the installation file for it execute it.

I have the following code in my `chain`:

```
  <ExePackage Id="Net45" Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Setup" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
    SourceFile="F:\Net Framework Install.exe"
    InstallCondition="NOT(Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45)" />
```

And I also declare the following fragment:

```
  <Fragment Id="InstallConditionChecks">
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
  </Fragment>
```

Finally, I believe I am referencing all of the right wix libraries needed to detect the .net installtion:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
```

The issue is thet even though I have a test machine that definitely has the .Net framework 4.5 installed, the installer still tries to install it (which leads to the .net installer trying to repair the installtion).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

There's two issues here.  The main problem is that `PropertyRef` is for MSIs, not bundles.  You need to use a `RegistrySearchRef`.  The other problem is that you're putting detection logic in `InstallCondition`, but that belongs in `DetectCondition`.  Remove your `InstallCondition` and use the same `DetectCondition` that the NetFx extension uses: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx451.wxs

```
<?define NetFx451MinRelease = 378675 ?>
<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />
<ExePackage DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx451MinRelease)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the registry of the target machine for the target framework you are looking for have a look at this tutorial, it will show you how to detect the Net Framework (RegistrySearch)and even shows how to make it work for Win32 or Win64.

Tutorial [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/node/76)